# Installation of Serviio on 14.4

Tags: software-installation, streaming, media, .sh

I have little Linux experience and I am completely new to Ubuntu.

I would like to install Serviio media server so that I can stream media from my PC to my TV. Serviio, however, is not available in the Software center.
If I download the package from the official Serviio site, then there is an instruction to create a config file (which I hope I completed correctly), and then to run the program. How can I do that? Ubuntu is opening the .sh file with a text editor..

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have seen this, but I do not understand it, it is a bit too high level for me. Where shall I write all these commands? In Terminal? In which folder? How to create and save scripts?

Comment: @DuminduMahawela The instructions in your link are obsolete for Ubuntu 14.04 and beyond.

Comment: Thank you, @karel! Can I find somewhere guidance what to do in 14.04 environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found on the internet a solution that worked for me.
[http://www.tylergale.com/?p=77](http://www.serviio.org/download)

I am posting it here for future reference if someone else has the same problem

1. Install Java. The suggestion was to install Java 7, but I couldn't run Serviio later, got some version mismatch error. I installed 8 and this solved the problem.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

2. Install FFMPEG

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg -y
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install ffmpeg

3. Download Serviio from the official site http://www.serviio.org/download and extract it in your desired destination folder. I personally called it 'serviio' and placed it in Home
4. Give permissions

> sudo chown -R YOURUSER:YOURUSER SERVIOFOLDER (e.g. sudo chown -R tyler:tyler /home/tyler/serviio)

5. Run from terminal

> sudo sh SERVIIOFOLDER/bin/serviio.sh
>   
>   and
>
> sudo sh SERVIIOFOLDER/bin/serviio-console.sh

I personally had problems to run it from terminal, but I managed to run it from GUI instead.

Comment: Looks like you found a better solution already! ;-)